# mySQL tutorial for writing SQL statements and DB scripts

Tags: mysql

*Thanks in advance*.

Is there a tutorial (preferablly free) out there that'll walk me through how to write mySQL statements?

I'm not interested in learning about installing and configuring mySQL since this is something handled by experts and I wouldn't have permissions to do this anyway.

Specifically, what I'm looking for is a tutorial that utilizes a database (Sakila perhaps?) that actually teaches how to write mySQL commands, AND that has questions for me to answer (via written SQL statements) with the accompanying correct results so I can verify my work.  I was hoping for at least a beginning and intermediate mySQL tutorial.  But without the correct answers / results, I can't possibly know if the SQL statements I'm writing are correct results or not.

I haven't really seen many tutorials that focus strictly on learning SQL statements and writing scripts, and I've seen none that have a thorough Q&A (with results) section.

If I have to pay for a tutorial, that's fine.  I just want to find one that focuses on learning to write SQL statements and scripts and that stays away from configuring and administering type learning.

Any help you can provide is greatly appreciated.

KJ

Answer (score 0):

I started out with an oreilly online course.
I know its not a tutorial, but if you are prepared to pay, its the better choice
For what you get its not that expensive and you'll come out of it with a very strong base.
If you are looking for strictly database:
[Database Administration Certificate](http://www.oreillyschool.com/certificate-programs/database-administration/)
Or a mix with a programming language (gives better insight to usage)
[PHP/SQL Programming Certificate](http://www.oreillyschool.com/certificate-programs/php-sql-programming/)

Also I found a really nice site with a lot of common and useful sql queries that you can use to learn some neat tricks
[Common MySQL Queries](http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/queries.php)

I hope this helps you and good luck